# How can I convert Org to reStructuredText extension for Sphinx Doc

Tags: org-mode

Initially I was writing my documentation in `README.md` file as a markdown format. I can than convert the markdown file into [reStructuredText](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html)(`rst`) extension for Sphinx Doc using `pandoc --from=markdown --to=rst --output=index.rst index.md` ; its solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30952996/2402577).

Now I am writing my documenration as in `README.org` file. Is it possible to convert files in `org` directly to rst extension for Sphinx Doc? or should I first convert org into markdown and then into rst format?

Comment: You might want to try out [ox-rst](https://github.com/msnoigrs/ox-rst). The main problem with going through Markdown will be the fact that there are many Markdown formats and there is no necessary relation between what `ox-md.el` will produce and what `pandoc` requires to produce rst: it will be a trial-and-error process.

Comment: This generated `rst` format seems different than pandoc generates. Like `1 Setup
-------------
` where should not be any number before each item in general

Comment: I guess the question is: does Sphinx like it or not? If not, you should open an issue at the ox-rst site.

Comment: I iterate through multiple github repos that has .rst files and non of the have numbering before the headers. Like `ox-rst` generates as:`1.4.1.2 Create app password`  // opened issue: https://github.com/msnoigrs/ox-rst/issues/57

Comment: Org pandoc Org -> rst?

Comment: @mankoff How can I apply `Org pandoc Org` to `rst`?